# Wave Function of Particle in Nuclear Reaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, nuclear-physics

I was thinking and came up with the question of what happens to the wave function of a particle that decays into energy, say a neutron in a nuclear reaction. I know that conservation of probability requires that the probability of finding the particle anywhere in space is 1.

Therefore, it seems to me that the energy has to be dealt with in the wave function of the particle. I have a feeling that this has something to do with the Hamiltonian operator present in Schrödiner's equation, but I can't seem to find anything confirming or proving that incorrect.

Anyone have an answer to how the wave function of a particle deals with decay into energy, or otherwise know of something I can read on the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you're thinking in terms of Quantum Mechanics, which considers the conservation of probability and the conservation of the number of particles.

The problem of annihilation of particles to energy (to photons, for example) is studied accurately under Quantum Field Theory, a theory, in which the total energy is conserved, and which takes relativity into account.

Basically, in quantum field theory, you don't have a "Wave function", but you have a Quantized Field, which changes from one form to another.

Read more here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory